# How to create calculated date field in correct order (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I have a timestamp field in MySQL, but I want to just GROUP by the Year, Month, and Week. In this case, I'm calculating counts of system errors by week.

Now, I can do a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR( ERRDATE ) AS YEAR,
    MONTH ( ERRDATE ) AS MONTH,
    WEEK ( ERRDATE ) AS WEEK,
    COUNT( DISTINCT ( ERRMSG ) ) AS ErrorCount
```

(GROUP BY CLAUSE OMITTED)

But that query gives me three columns (YEAR, MONTH, WEEK) which I don't want.

What I want is a single column with the calculated date in descending order and a second column with the error value so I can pass these data to a graphing program.

I've tried using CONCAT, but the problem there is that CONCAT is for strings and the calculated dates are in the wrong order. I tried using CAST and CONVERT, and even a nested CAST in the CONCAT, but I could still not get a single calculated date column ordered correctly from the timestamp field.

For example, this approach doesn't work correctly:

```
CONCAT(YEAR(ERRDATE), MONTH(ERRDATE), WEEK(ERRDATE)) as THEDATE
```

So, how do I get a single calculated field from the tiemstamp field in the correct order?

Thanks much in advance,

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: How can you group by month and week? A week is not "part" of a month. However - You can use [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and specifiers with leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If your current query already give you the result you want just en capsule it on a sub query

```
SELECT CONCAT ( year, month, week) as period, ErrorCount
FROM (
    SELECT YEAR ( ERRDATE ) AS YEAR,
           MONTH ( ERRDATE ) AS MONTH,
           WEEK ( ERRDATE ) AS WEEK,
           COUNT( DISTINCT ( ERRMSG ) ) AS ErrorCount
    ...
   ) as t
```

Comment: Thanks I had thought about the subquery but was going for a simpler solution. :)

Comment: Well you didn't put the GROUP BY condition, so I went with the solution knew can work

Comment: No worries. I appreciate your kind posting. It's excellent also. These postings really get me thinking about all the great ways there are to solve query challenges.

Answer (score 0):

You query should be:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(ERRDATE,"%Y,%m,%U") AS Period,
    COUNT( DISTINCT ( ERRMSG ) ) AS ErrorCount
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY Period;
```

See more about [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) function